# What is this flowering shrub from Algonquin Park?

Tags: identification

Saw this plant growing to heights of three to four feet (one to one and a half metres) in a mixed pine and deciduous forest in Algonquin Park (USDA zone 3).  The berries or drupes are black.  The leaf is almost ready to drop and is pictured on the left.  The leaf on the right is from Viburnum trilobum "Wentworth" from my garden.

What is this plant?  It looks like a native viburnum but I don't know which species.

[image: Viburnum?]

Comment: This is a good question, particularly the inclusion of a scale, leaf and inflorescence. It would be helpful to have a piece of a branch with leaves as well. I don't have a key specific to the area (There are ~120 species in North and Central America), but a few additional things that would make life easier for someone who does: Are the leaves/branches pubescent? Where? What was the color and size of the flowers? *V. acerifolium* in Bailey's *Manual of Cultivated Plants* sounds close, but the range only extends to Minnesota.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was concerned that [*Viburnum acerifolium*](http://www.wildflower.org/plants/result.php?id_plant=VIAC) (Dockmackie) did not appear to extend into Canada. Upon doing a bit more research, it does appear that *V. acerifolium* is [found in S.E. Quebec and Ontario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viburnum_acerifolium).

[USDA link](http://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=viac)

[image: *V. acerifolium*]

> Deciduous shrub to 6 ft., ... **lvs. maple-like, 3-lobed, 2-5 in. long, coarsely dentate, with acuminate lobes**, pubescent or at length almost glabrous ... in **long-stalked cymes 2-3 in. across**: fr. oval, 1/3in. long, red changing to **purple_black**. N.B. to Minn. south to N.C.

Description from L.H. Bailey's *Manual of Cultivated Plants* (emphasis added)